# How to draw a barplot from counts data in R?

Tags: r

I have a data-frame 'x'

[image: X]

I want barplot like this
[image]

I tried

```
barplot(x$Value, names.arg = x$'Categorical variable')
ggplot(as.data.frame(x$Value), aes(x$'Categorical variable')
```

Nothing seems to work properly. In barplot, all axis labels (freq values) are different. ggplot is filling all bars to 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to read the `ggplot` documentation. `ggplot` requires a few things, including `data` and `aes()`. You've got both of those statements there but you're not using them correctly.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(256)

dat <- 
  data.frame(variable = c("a", "b", "c"), 
             value = rnorm(3, 10))

dat %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "blue") +
  coord_flip()
```

Here, I'm piping my `dat` to `ggplot` as the `data` argument and using the names of the `x` and `y` variables rather than passing a `data$...` value. Next, I add the `geom_bar()` statement and I have to use `stat = "identity"` to tell `ggplot` to use the actual values in my `value` rather than trying to plot the count of the number.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Only problem is that it is sorting the plot by x = variable. How to sort it by value?

Comment: You need to change the levels of the `variable` factor to be sorted by `value`. See `?factor()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try plotting using geom_bar(). Following code generates what you are looking for.

```r
df = data.frame(X = c("A","B C","D"),Y = c(23,12,43))
ggplot(df,aes(x=X,y=Y)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `stat = "identity"` in `geom_bar()`.

```
dat <- data.frame("cat" = c("A", "BC", "D"),
                  "val" = c(23, 12, 43))
ggplot(dat, aes(as.factor(cat), val)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
coord_flip()
```